# factory girl has_many when child is required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a two models `Post` and `Image` . Post can't be created without `images`.

```
class Post <  ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images 
  validates :images , presence: true
end

class Image <  ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post
   validates :post_id , presence: true
   validates :name , presence: true
end
```

Now, i am trying to set `factory girl` for `post` and `image`. I am okay with `image` factory girl but can't able to set `post` factory girl which should have image in it.

```
#image
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :image do
    name "something"
    post_id 121
  end
end

#post 
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
     title "foo bar"
     after(:create) do |post,evaluator|
      create_list :image , 3 , post: post
     end
  end
end
```

But i still ended up validation error on `post` that `images should be present`. This error does make sense but how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
     title "foo bar"
     after(:build) do |post,evaluator|
       post.images << (build_list :image , 3 , post: post)
     end
  end
end
```